# GTK slider for media seeking

Tags: gtk

I'm using GtkHScale (which is a slider) to perform seeking in a media player. I connected the "value_changed" signal of the widget to a callback so that the user can seek. I also set a timer, that will update the widget every 250ms so that it will show the current position in track. Unfortunately GTK fires the "value_changed" signal regardless of whether the slider was clicked by the user or updated by the timer. I tried seeking in the "clicked" signal, and the callback was fired, but it always sought to the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of whether the user is moving the slider by connecting to the button-press-event and button-release-event signals. When the user presses the mouse button you want to block the updates from the player so they don't move the slider when the user is trying to seek. In the button release handler you can unblock the updates.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to surround calls to gtk_range_set_value() for playback updates with g_signal_handler_block/unblock [1] calls. This allows the value and UI of the slider to be updated without triggering specific value changed handlers.

Python GTK+ 3 example showing on_value_changed is only called with interactive scrubbing:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib

def on_value_changed(hscale):
    print('value-changed: %s' % hscale.get_value())

def on_timeout(hscale, handler_id):
    # Block value-changed handler during timed playback updates.
    with hscale.handler_block(handler_id):
        hscale.set_value(hscale.get_value() + 1)
    return True

hscale = Gtk.HScale()
hscale.set_range(0, 100)
handler_id = hscale.connect('value-changed', on_value_changed)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_size_request(500, 50)
window.add(hscale)
window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()

GLib.timeout_add(100, on_timeout, hscale, handler_id)

Gtk.main()
```

[1] https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-handler-block